# Finding an equation of a plane that is perpendicular to a given parametric line through the origin.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have that $(x,y,z) = (3t, t, -2t)$. I have already shown that this is a vector subspace of $\Bbb R^3$. Now I need to find a plane perpendicular to this through $(0,0,0)$.

Secondly, I need to find and orthonormal basis $B = \{u,v,w\}$ for $\Bbb R^3$ such that {u} is also a basis for $(x,y,z) = (3t, t, -2t)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The direction vector of the line is normal to the plane. So $\vec n =\langle 3,1,-2\rangle$. You also have a point $(0,0,0)$.

$$P \ :\ \  3(x-0)+1(y-0)-2(z-0)=0$$

To find a basis of your hyperplane, you have:

$$x=-\dfrac{1}{3}y+\dfrac{2}{3}z$$

So

$$ \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix} =     y\begin{pmatrix} -\dfrac{1}{3} \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} + z\begin{pmatrix} \dfrac{2}{3} \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} $$

Thus a basis is

$$\left\{\begin{pmatrix} -\dfrac{1}{3} \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} \dfrac{2}{3} \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}\right\} $$

All that's left is to apply Grahm-Schmidt and then normalize the vectors.

$u$ will of course be $\dfrac{\vec n}{||\vec n||}$ which is already orthogonal to both of these.

Answer (score 0):

If you fix t to be any real number not equal to zero, you get a vector. Notice that for all t these vectors are the same up to a scalar. This means that any vector orthogonal to a fixed t is also orthogonal to all the t in your parametric line. To find a vector orthogonal to the line, simply take the dot product with an arbitrary 3-tuple (x,y,z) and set it equal to zero. Magically, you get the equation to a plane.